# Date Isuue in Mail Merge

Tags: microsoft-word

Im Trying to merge an excel document as shown below to word with the fields i required.

date            name
march 24 2014   Kiran

when im trying to insert the date it is showing in a format as shown.

3/24/2014

when im trying to edit the date format to 24 march 2014 it is taking the current system date instead of the date i specified as shown

24 march 2014 ( this is the format i want )

29 march 2014 ( this is the format system is showing)

Kindly help me in this regard. I want the same date to be in a different format. i tried using the codes {MERGEFIELD MyDate \@ "d MMMM yyyy"} as well.

Comment: So just to be sure, if you use { MERGEFIELD MyDate } in your document, you see 3/24/2014 ? In that case adding \@ "d MMMM yyyy" to the field  is the right thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the format of the cells containing the dates in your excel file from 'General' or 'Date' to 'Text' format.

In excel go Home Tab>Number Box on the Ribbon>Text on the Drop Down Menu (the drop down menu will probably say 'General')

Then retry the mail merge.

- Office 2013

Comment: FYI, formatting cells in Excel has no effect on mail merge formats.  If you want something other than default you need to use field switches.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format--I just tested it and it works:

```
{MERGEFIELD MyDate \@ "dd MMMM yyyy"}
```